# Removing elements from title and url of page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery which pulls results from a PHP script. When a user queries something, their query is displayed in the title of the page as "**QUERY** - My Search Script" and in the url of the page as #**QUERY**. However, when you delete all the text from the search box the **#** still stays in the url and the title says " - My Search Script". How can I make it so when all of the search box content is cleared, the script removed the title and the #?

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash=query;
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search Script';
            $('#result').empty();
        }
        else {
            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(search);
            document.title = search + ' - My Search Script';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'search.php',
                data: {q: search, category: 'web'},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#result').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've used the `data` option of `$.ajax` so that you don't need to build the url yourself.

I don't think you can guarantee to get rid of the hash in the URL: Some browsers remove it, others don't.

Comment: I see a couple of problems with this approach. 1) Changing the hash on every keyup event will add a large number of entries into the browser's history list and make the back button useless to the user. And 2) When the search is empty I would expect the contents of '#result' to reflect this, not to display the previous search results.

Comment: @vitch: I hadn't thought about point 1, since the OP requested it on keyup. Good point though. Well spotted on point two though!

Answer (score 1):

You can tidy the `<title>` up easy enough but you won't be able to consistently remove the `#` from the URL once you've set a hash. The only browser that seems to get rid of it is Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    var search=$(this).val();
    var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
    var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
    window.location.hash=query;
    // You may want to use a better title than '\xa0' (blank)
    document.title = search=='' ? '\xa0' : search+" - My Search Script";

    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:yt_url,
      dataType:"html",
      success:function(response){
        $("#result").html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Might be better not to bother with the ajax request if the user hasn't typed a search term, as in my answer.

Comment: @Eric: I know what you're getting at but maybe the `search.php` script will return either no results (much like how Google Instant works when the search field is blank) or a message prompting to enter a search term will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response);
                if (query == "") {
                    window.location.hash=query;
                    document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
                } else {
                    window.location.hash=query;
                    document.title="My Search Script";
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The changes I made are:

- Don't update the title and hash until the new data is loaded.
- Behave differently if the searched for query is an empty string.

Comment: **-1** That won't work! What do you expect `"My Search Script";` to do!?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to do anything! Looks like I deleted a little bit too much when trying to edit text in the text field on the site. Edited to what I intended to post, thanks for the friendly note letting me know about my mistake...

Comment: No worries, I've removed the downvote now that you've fixed it